# Share local area connection with multiple TAPs

Tags: networking, vpn, ics

I'm setting up an VPN server. In this server I want to have 2 different encryptions (1024, 2048), each one in different ports. So I created 2 TAP adapters, and shared the local area connection with the first one. After connecting on the client, I can navigate with all my packets going thru the server. Now I need to do the same thing for the second adapter, but Windows don't let-me share simultaneously with both adapters.
Here's a screen about what I'm talking about:
[Screenshot.](http://s18.postimg.org/bwyeclk3d/Screen.png)

Is possible to make all this TAPs shared with the local connection?